# How to assign text colors when working with Vuetify themes

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm quite new to Vuetify and struggling to figure out how themes, components and text colors work together (if they do at all).

I want to work with theme color names in my templates like `primary, secondary, warning, error` and assign colors to those keywords by adding a new theme or overwriting the existing one.

This all works out of the box but the problem is I can't figure out how to set text colors in the same way. I want to assign a `primary-text-color`, `secondary-text-color`, etc. and have it automatically use the correct text color by default.

Text colors seem to change automatically when I change the color on buttons but nowhere else.

If I add a theme color to buttons, Vuetify automatically changes the text color to be readable, for example (just using the default theme):

```html
<v-btn color='primary'>Test</v-btn>
```

Text will change to [primary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFITj.png) and the button will be perfectly usable
while a lighter color will have [dark text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPPYx.png):

```html
<v-btn>Test</v-btn>
```

But other components don't behave the same. For example a `v-app-bar` component with [default color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtyeG.png) has dark text on a light background, but a [primary app bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9hcG.png) keeps the dark text on a blue background.

It looks like I need to explicitly change the text color with a helper class or similar, and even then I'd have to use something like `white--text` instead of `primary--text` (which just applies the actual primary color to text).

I think I've read all the docs on the website but I can't find any reference to this particular problem

Sorry for the links to images, I don't have enough flair to embed them in my post.

Comment: I would like to know the same.

Comment: @TorHaugen I'm pretty sure there is no way to do it currently. Explicitly using something like `white--text` is the only way, silly as it is. I ended up just using that plus `dark` where needed. It feels like a big gap to have themes but no way to link text colours to the themes.

Answer (score 0):

currently, this works primary--text

```
<v-list-item-title v-if="company_name" class="title primary--text">
            {{ company_name.company_name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
```